# Cannot Connect to Database Server

Tags: server, mysql

I'm having trouble installing MySQL Server.
Everytime I try to connect to local server with MySQL Workbench I get this message:

> "Your connection attempt failed for user 'root' from your host to server at localhost:3306:
> Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
>
> Please:
>
> 1 Check that mysql is running on server localhost
> 2 Check that mysql is running on port 3306 (note: 3306 is the default, but this can be changed)
> 3 Check the root has rights to connect to localhost from your address (mysql rights define what clients can connect to the server and from which machines)
> 4 Make sure you are both providing a password if needed and using the correct password for localhost connecting from the host address you're connecting from"

I'm running a freshly installied Ubuntu 18.04.
These are the packeges I have installed on my system:

```
libmysqlclient20:amd64
libmysqlcppconn7v5:amd64
mysql-client
mysql-client-5.7
mysql-client-core-5.7
mysql-common
mysql-server
mysql-server-5.7
mysql-server-core-5.7
mysql-utilities
mysql-workbench
mysql-workbench-data   
python-mysql.connector
```

I've tried this: `mysql -u root -p`

Then I'm prompted to enter a password, but during installation I was never asked to create one to begin with.
And then I get the error no matter what pass I give:

```
ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
```

Comment: Try `sudo mysql -u root`. MariaDB at least uses the unix user authentication.

Answer (score 0):

After a fresh install the root password could be blank. It is recommended to run

```
mysql_secure_installation
```

to secure your mysql server and set a root password.